# Does not have feature like JPA's AttributeConverter in spring-data-cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

According to the spring-data-cassandra document, a converter that performs object mapping of cassandra side data is applied to the scope of the session (or more). So I can not limit a converter to a specific table / colum, because a converter is simply defined with a source type and a target type.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#cassandra.custom-converters

I have a blob type column for each table. And I want each column to be deserialized to a different object per table, but I can not do that in the above way.

If you have a good solution, please share it. Thank you.

Comment: Care to post some example code. If every table's blob type is different, you can create a converter per target type.

Comment: @mp911de You are right. I mistook one source type for conversion to only one target type. I have see that the appropriate converter is chosen to fit the entity type.